# add ajax button in django to update user`s choice

Tags: python, django

I have followed the tutorial by Mozilla described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Tutorial_local_library_website) and have made some modifications to make it into a movie library.

I would like to add the option for a user when he opens a movie to be able to mark it as "seen". I would like to do that using ajax so the button the user would click would change as well without refreshing the page.

This is the model used to store the user choice

```
class Seenit(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    movieid = models.ForeignKey('Movie', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    haveyouseenit = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.username}|{self.movieid.id}"
```

this is from the `urls.py`

```
re_path(r'^add_to_seen/(?P<pk>.*)', views.Addseen.as_view(), name='add_to_seen')
```

This is from the `views.py`

```
class Addseen(generic.DetailView):
    model = Seenit

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.is_ajax():
            check = get_object_or_404(Seenit, movieid=id, username=request.user.get_username())
            if not check.haveyouseenit:
                check.haveyouseenit == True
                check.save()
                return HttpResponse("1")
            else:
                check.haveyouseenit == False
                check.save()
                return HttpResponse("0")
```

and this is from the `movie_details.html` showing the button along with an attempt I made for the ajax button.

```
    <div id="seen">
        {%  if user.is_authenticated  %}
            <button class="add_button" id="seen">Have seen</button>
            <b style="color: #3b97f4" id="message"></b>
            {%  if seen %}
                <script>
                    $("#seen").css({"background-color": "#f4b6e0", "color": "white"});
                </script>
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
                    <script>
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $("#seen").click(function () {
                            $.get("/add_to_seen/{{ movie.id }}", function (msg) {
                                if (msg === "1") {
                                    $("#seen").css({"background-color": "#f4f15f", "color": "white"});
                                    $("#message").html("Added to Seen!").fadeIn("fast").fadeOut("slow");
                                }
                                if (msg === "0") {
                                    $("#seen").css({"background-color": "white", "color": "black"});
                                    $("#message").html("Deleted from Seen!").fadeIn("fast").fadeOut("slow");
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    });
                </script>
    </div>
```

The button appears when i visit a movie, but it does not do anything. I am very novice with django and javascript/ajax so any information you might provide please explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button class="add_button" id="seen" onclick="Seen({{movie.id}})">Have seen</button>
```

in javascript:

```
function Seen(n){
var patch = '{% url "add_to_seen" %}'
info = {'pk':n, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken':"{{ csrf_token }}"}

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: patch,
  data:info,
    datatype:'json',

success: function(){

console.log('success')
return

}


})
}
```

views:

```
 def Addseen(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        response_json = request.POST
        response_json = json.dumps(response_json)
        data = json.loads(response_json)
        pk = data['pk']
           #do whatever you have to do with the model.

       return JsonResponse(safe=False)
```

If you need further help, lemme know.

Comment: I do not really understand how the views part works. What information does the `data` holds? I would like to access the movieid which is in the url submitted and also the username of the user, but I am not sure how to proceed with the `data`

Comment: anything you would want to send back to the frontend, which is the point of an Ajax request. For example, I assume you would want a "mark as unseen" as well as "seen"? You could put that in the data, Here I only did it so you could see how it works.

Comment: i think i can not use the `if request.method == 'POST'` you are using in the views.py if I have defined it as a class. In my views I have it as `class Addseen(generic.DetailView):`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Using a class based view for an AJAX request You want to use the regular kind. No reason to use class.

Comment: I edited my answer to show you. You also need to remove as.view() from URL.

Comment: ok i got it. One more thing, I have to pass the `pk` as well in order to have it in the views.py so i can search for the movie, is this correct?

Comment: Yes, but isn't it in your URL? If not, 1) send it with seen() when you click - ie: onclick=Seen({{id}}), 2) alter the javascript to accept an argument - ie: function Seen(pk_){}  3) then add it to info dictionary - {'pk':pk_} ... 4)on the backend -  check = get_object_or_404(Seenit, movieid=data['pk'])

Comment: in the javascript i added `var patch = '{% url "add_to_seen" id=movie.id %}';` so the id is in the url now. But is is not working. The console logs `reference error $ is not defined`. [This](https://pastebin.com/raw/BD0tzYz4) is the javascript and the views.py as I have them now.

Comment: re_path(r'^add_to_seen/(?P<pk>.*)', views.Addseen.as_view(), name='add_to_seen') --- change <pk> to <id>

Comment: I have already changed that and removed the `as_view()` since it no longer is a class. Added also to the template this line `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` and now i do not have the `reference error` but still it does not do anything

Comment: try "print("Hi!") in view. Does it show up when you call with Ajax?

Comment: the `Hi` is printed and also there is an error `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'`

Comment: return JsonResponse(safe=False, data) --- try it like that. You're very close! Your html and ajax are working. The problem is now only in your views.

Comment: from django.http import JsonResponse & import json--- don't forget to add those to your imports!